# Terraform: Error launching source instance: InvalidAMIID.Malformed

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Going through [terraform tutorial](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/aws-build?in=terraform/aws-get-started) I stumbled upon this error.

```
Error: Error launching source instance: InvalidAMIID.NotFound: The image id '[ami-830c94e3]' does not exist
    status code: 400, request id: 4c3e0252-c3a5-471e-8b57-3f6e349628af
```

This is my code. The only change that I did was was region change from `us-west-2` to `eu-central-1`

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region = "eu-central-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami = "ami-830c94e3"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It was simple. Apparently, `AMI` for Amazon Images of each region is different. I had to copy the `AMI` of the image that was present in my region. For example **ami-07dfba995513840b5** is the id for **Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 (HVM), SSD Volume Type** in **eu-central-1** region. Go to AWS console, click EC2 from all services list, next click launch instance and find the `AMI` of an image of your interest.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of hardcoding AMI IDs you should consider using the [`aws_ami` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ami) instead.

This allows you to more easily specify the type of AMI you want and have Terraform automatically use that AMI, including the option to have it automatically update the AMI in use when newer AMIs matching your criteria are available. It will also make it easier to manage using the same AMI in different regions as the AMI ID is different for each region it is copied to.

The [`aws_instance` resource documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance) has a good example of using the most recent Ubuntu 20.04 AMI published by Canonical in the region:

```
data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["099720109477"] # Canonical
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type = "t3.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}
```

If you run the following in different regions it will automatically use the correct Ubuntu 20.04 AMI for the region. It will also recreate the instance with the latest AMI when a newer Ubuntu 20.04 AMI is published by Canonical.

Comment: Very clever. Thanks for sharing this tip!

Comment: What about the Terraform Block en this file, does it work without it?... Im asking because Iyour file file only has "data" and "resource" block!

Comment: @CristianetooGeova what makes you think it wouldn't work? Have you tried running it?

Comment: Just be aware if using this image lookup and there is an updated instance you can't deploy any changes (e.g. increase disk) without re-creating the instance.

Comment: If you don't want it to recreate your instance you can use `lifecycle.ignore_changes` on the `ami` parameter. That way you still keep a more declarative way to describe the AMI you use and have the option to have it auto upgrade to a new AMI when appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you the Zone is registered for you in which you are creating instance.
Verify it:
EC2 Dashboard -> Service Health -> Zones

Zone name   Zone ID
us-east-2a  use2-az1
us-east-2b  use2-az2
us-east-2c  use2-az3

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this issue last night. Make sure your provider region, in your `.tf` file, matches your AWS Management console region. My provider region was "us-east-1", but the region in the Management Console was "us-east-2".

Answer (score 1):

check your Amazon console region sometime is default selected differently.

As per region, your AMI ID is different

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when trying to create an **Ubuntu 20.04** AWS EC2 instance using **Terraform**.

I was running into this error when I run the `terraform apply` command:

> Error: Error launching source instance: InvalidAMIID.Malformed: Invalid id: "data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id" (expecting "ami-...")
> status code: 400, request id: 9cb0ddbc-1f5e-43e7-bef2-541832aa002e

My code looks like this:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["099720109477"] # Canonical
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  ami = "data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

The issue was that I put `data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id` in quotes which is a call/invocation operation of the `data` function::

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  ami = "data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
```

I had to remove the quotes from `data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id`:

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
```

So my code looked like this afterwards:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["099720109477"] # Canonical
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  ami = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}
```

This time when I ran `terraform apply` command,it printed the correct **ami id** for the **ubuntu 20.04** aws ec2 instance in my specified region:

```
data.aws_ami.ubuntu: Refreshing state... [id=ami-0885b1f6bd170450c]
```

and then created the aws instance resource.

**Note**: The specified name for the `resource` which is `ec2` can be of any value of your choice. You can name it `web` or whatever name you desire:

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

check aws credentails using aws configure command, check wheater secretkey,accesskey and region are matching with your configuration code.
if the region is different try changing the region based on where ami is presen

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of available Amazon EC2 images like this:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-images
```

Note it returns the images in your default region!

To get the details about specific images:

```
$ aws --region eu-central-1 ec2 describe-images --include-deprecated --image-ids ami-002c3687c157a3668 ami-0154a0c4f87fc839d
```